Is there a Filepond event for the moment when the user has chosen their file and clicks Open?
I'm using the latest version of Filepond in native JS. Occasionally I see a long delay between when the user has chosen their file (clicked "Open") and when the "initfile" event is triggered. Ideally I would like to show a spinner during this delay to inform the user to wait. I don't see another event on the list that I could use to trigger this spinner.
Does anyone have a suggestion?
